# Silverlight 5 datagrid is missing data

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I am trying to bind an xml data set to a Silverlight data grid. There are 21 rows in my xml The grid shows the heading ok and the 21 rows but the rows show no data. If I look at the ItemsSource property it shows the row date  as being there.

I am having a problem posting all the code because of the edits that Stack Overflow does. Here is the key piece. If you need to see anything else, I will post it as comments.

```
grdData.ItemsSource = cloData.LoadData("Sample.xml")

public class clsData
{
    public System.Collections.IEnumerable LoadData(string pName)
    {
        XDocument nutritionsDoc = XDocument.Load(pName);

        List<Nutrition> data = (from nutrition in nutritionsDoc.Descendants("Nutrition")
                                select new Nutrition
                                {
                                    Group = nutrition.Attribute("Group").Value,
                                    Name = nutrition.Attribute("Name").Value,
                                    Quantity = nutrition.Attribute("Quantity").Value
                                }).ToList();

        return data;
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: does data has values before assigning to itemsSource.

Answer (score 0):

I just made the nutrition class a public class and it was magically solved.

Bob